# Get User information in pages which are not part of any flow in Spring webflow

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-security, spring-webflow-2

In my application i am using Spring Security, Spring Web Flow and JSF. I have defined flows and can extract user information using #{currentUser.name} in pages which are part of flow. But there are some pages like home page which are not part of any flow and is outside the flow. I want to display user name in home page if user is authenticated but i am not able to extract it. Main reason might be that for webflow, i have configured this in webflow.xml

```
<flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
 <flow-execution-listeners>
   <listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
   <listener ref="securityListener"/>
 </flow-execution-listeners>
</flow-executor>
```

Since its configured for flows only, that's why currentUser object is available for all pages inside flow. Now my question is "is it possible to currentUser object in non flow pages".

Answer (score 0):

I am do not know about `currentUser` object. But you can try [Spring Security JSP taglib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#taglibs):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

for these non flow pages. Hope it helps.